# How can we scale up instances in AWS by schedule action

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops, aws-auto-scaling

Is this possible in AWS auto-scaling that I want to scale-up my instances by every 5 min by 2. That mean if my running instances are 2 so after 5 min it will be 4 then next 5 min it will be 6 and so on...
How will I achieve this in auto-scaling (Schedule action, Policies etc.)

Comment: _WHY_ would you want to do this? Normally, Auto scaling is used to _react_ to workload, rather than always increasing workloads. If you are expecting a particular capacity (eg workers starting at 9am), you can use a _schedule_ to trigger an Auto Scaling policy at a particular time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by auto-scaling group policy easily, select the cooldown period to be 5 mins and add a policy action to increase 2 instances if the CPU usage >=0, this will add 2 instances every 5 mins to the auto-scaling group

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can do it.

Something like this, it takes a form of crontab every 10 minutes
[Minute] [Hour] [Day_of_Month] [Month_of_Year] [Day_of_Week].

```
aws autoscaling put-scheduled-update-group-action --scheduled-action-name my-recurring-action \
  --auto-scaling-group-name my-asg --recurrence "10 0 * * *" --desired-capacity 3
```

more details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/schedule_time.html)

Comment: It will only increase the 3 instances and after that it will not increase any instance

Comment: I just gave you an example, you can replace it with 500. you don't want your resources to scale up infinitely.